# how to create iterators for synthetic data?

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I am making iterators using `boost::iterator_facade<>` for synthetic data. The data are only accessible by calling a function on a handle. The handle is wrapped into `MyHandle`. I have figured out that I need to use `MyHandle` for both `Value` and `Reference` template parameters. So the iterator declaration looks like this:

```
class MyIterator
    : public boost::iterator_facade<
        MyIterator
        , MyHandle
        , boost::forward_traversal_tag
        , MyHandle
    >
```

Is this the only way how to do this kind of thing? Or is there a better way how to create iterators for synthetic data? Also, the `boost::forward_traversal_tag` seems like it does not convey the artificiality of the data well, should the code use a different iterator tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::function_input_iterator` wraps a generator function in an iterator.  Dereferencing the iterator calls the function and returns its result:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/iterator/doc/function_input_iterator.html

Comment: Well, the data are structured, so a simple function will not do.

Comment: When you say a "simple function", do you mean "a function without state that persists between calls"?  This is not a barrier, because you can construct a function_input_iterator with any callable object, including a stateful struct that defines the function call operator.